# Unable to access class variable C#

Tags: c#, wcf, methods

When I try to access service class variable inside a class, it shows some error. However when I try to access the same Class variable inside a method, it works fine.

```
Eg:
public class Sample
{
ServiceName.ServiceClass variable =  new ServiceName.ServiceClass();
variable.member = 10; //This shows error variable not defined
}

public class Sample
{
public void methodName()
{
ServiceName.ServiceClass variable =  new ServiceName.ServiceClass();
variable.member = 10; //This works fine and allows value allocation
}
}
```

Comment: *I did not had time to read any documentation* - so we have to take our time to read the documentation for you?

Comment: You cant set any property outside of a method.

Comment: I am guessing you want to use constructor!
BTW what is the issue with method?

Comment: With `;` I get *Unexpected symbol '=' in class, struct, or interface member declaration*. Without it, I get *Unexpected symbol 'variable'*.

Comment: You need the `;`. For `Unexpected symbol 'variable'.` see @apomene's comment above. You can't write code outside of a function like that. The compiler won't let you. Consider @Oilid's solution below.

Comment: [I downvoted because research must be done to ask a good question](http://idownvotedbecau.se/noresearch/).

Answer (score 1):

Try this :

```
ServiceName.ServiceClass variable = new ServiceName.ServiceClass {member = 10};
```

Comment: As said above, you can't set any property outside of a method.

Answer (score 1):

@apomene is right, you cant set any property outside of a method. If you need to give a constant default value,add `=10;` in the end of the property's line.

Or, if you need to do it in a method, you can use a [constructor](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/constructors).Something like;

```
public Sample()
{
    member = 10;
}
```